# Integrating normal php session in codeigniter

Tags: php, facebook, codeigniter, session-cookies, codeigniter-2

I have been experiencing session in codeigniter but I have some failure since sometime I need to register session without using controller. For instance When a facebook user login in my app using FACEBOOK SDK this plugins use normal php session, so when I try to get them in codeigniter controller I fail; In other part when I register a session in a controller I will need to call the same session in other controllers or register base controller. Killing codeIgniter session does not remove SDK session and cookies. So How can I use normal session in CodeIgniter so that I don't loose SDK functionality. Thanks.

Comment: I think it might actually be easier to make Facebook use CI sessions than the other way around.

Answer (score 2):

A replacement of codeigniter's sessions is already available, It's called Native Sessions class, You just drop the files in their places & everything should work as expected.

https://github.com/appleboy/CodeIgniter-Native-Session

Comment: I tried to get the  library for native session. But the problem is this: I want to register being in index_view a session after a facebook user logged in using  $_SESSION['email']=$user_profile['email'];
       header("Location:home"); and when I try to get it in home_view with a simple echo <?php echo $_SESSION['email'];?> I get the error Message: Undefined index: email

Comment: You'll have to start the session at the beginning of your application, no matter where you're planning to use it. Using the native sessions class, it will give you access to session data using the usual codeigniter's sessions methods $this->session->userdata('something'); ... anyway if you're getting undefined index, it means you did not save it in the first place. show me some code so I can help you further.

Answer (score 1):

The facebook wrapper was written as it is for this very reason. Managing data used with or by the base class is done in this wrapper.

After assigning the CI superglobal to the facebook class in the constructor

```
$this->ci =& get_instance();
```

Replace all instances of

```
$_SESSION
```

With and the relevant information as it would have gone previously into $_SESSION

```
//Add data to the session
$this->ci->session->set_userdata();

//Remove data from the session
$this->ci->session->unset_userdata();
```

Comment: When I change: `$session_var_name = $this->constructSessionVariableName($key);
    $_SESSION[$session_var_name] = $value;` to `$session_var_name = $this->constructSessionVariableName($key);
    $fbkhmpsession=array('session_var_name' =>$session_var_name);
    $this->ci->session->set_userdata($fbkhmpsession);` in setPersistentData method in facebook class and get them in getPersistantData

Comment: changing `$session_var_name = $this->constructSessionVariableName($key);
    return isset($_SESSION[$session_var_name]) ?
      $_SESSION[$session_var_name] : $default;` to  `$session_var_name = $this->constructSessionVariableName($key);
    return isset($this->ci->session->userdata($session_var_name) ?
      $this->ci->session->userdata($session_var_name) : $default;`

Comment: I get the following error: __Fatal error: Can't use method return value in write context in C:\xampp\htdocs\hmplatform\facebook.php on line 119__